# Continuous monitoring of KMeans model post production

Tags: clustering, k-means

In the process of deploying a KMeans model for a customer segmentation use case into production. KMeans doesn’t produce the same results every time and after production cluster sizes and arrangements are bound to change.

What are some considerations to take into account after deploying a KMeans model into production and what metrics do you monitor?

Anyone have any experience with this/have any recourses to share?

Comment: See modified answer - to some extent your OP is an open-ended question, since you didn't report the variation in results as a function of feature transformation, cluster initiation method, distance metric used, or cluster validity method used.  As usual, the answer is: "It depends."

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, whenever the training data change you will experience "concept drift," where the model prediction changes with the input data.  Secondly, are you performing cluster validity analysis to determine the optimal number of clusters for your benchmark dataset?

An example cluster validity run output is shown below, and you can see that cluster validity based on Canberra and Chebychev distance metrics indicate that the bend in the "knee" occurs at about k=3 clusters.  If you're not first establishing the optimal number of clusters from a consensus benchmark training dataset from your cloud/server farm, then your K-means assessment can be all over the map.

[image]

As far as monitoring, I would periodically determine the optimal number of clusters and track the value of the silhouette distance, which gives an overall picture for how well the model clusters the data.  Lastly, there are a lot of methodologic issues which affect deployment outcomes related to your question, such as feature transformations employed, cluster (prototype) initiation method, distance metric employed, and cluster validity method used.

FYI - K-means is one of the worst clustering methods that can reveal the cluster separation of objects for datasets with known class separation.

Comment: Yes - I plotted the elbow curve and got that number at 5 clusters.